# JS uncaught syntax error when on server but not localhost

Tags: javascript, digital-ocean

I have a php variable which I am changing into JS array

orderform.blade:

```
    <?php
    foreach ($entries as $entry){
        $name[] = $entry->name;
        $quantity[] = $entry->quantity;
    }
    ?>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    var entries = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($entries) ?>');
//  console.log(entries);
    </script>
```

Then in my JS file I am using the variable

```
var output = entries.reduce(function (orderA, orderB){...
```

This works on local host perfectly. But when I put on digital ocean cloud server I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
Uncaught ReferenceError: entries is not defined at javascript.js:12
```

The missing ) error is highlighting this:

```
        var entries = JSON.parse('[{"id":2,"name":"Britannia","mint":"The Royal Mint","quantity":"3","weight":"31.15","price":"19.00","description":"Royal Mint flagship silver bullion. CGT free.","created_at":"2018-05-01 03:08:38","updated_at":"2018-05-01 03:27:23"},{"id":3,"name":"Maple Leaf","mint":"The Royal Canadian Mint","quantity":"12","weight":"31.15","price":"17.50","description":"Canada's flagship bullion coin. Prone to milk spots.","created_at":"2018-05-01 10:41:57","updated_at":"2018-05-01 10:41:57"}]');
```

What can cause this to work in one environment and not on another? How do I address this? I can not see any syntax error here?

Comment: The evil `Canada's` ... :)

Comment: Correct! What good eye for detail you have!

Comment: syntax highlighting is your friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is due to your string literal using apostrophe delimiter \' inside itself. You need to escape your JSON. Where is this JSON string generated?

What's formally happening:

```
'Canada's more characters... ')
```

StringLiteral **'Canada'** + [ lookahead ~= { **)** } ]

So, you obviously shouldn't just pass your raw JSON to JavaScript source. Escape quotes and apostrophes from your PHP server.

(I think `preg_replace` won't replace all occurrences of the quotes, but in JS I know `json.replace(/'"\''/g, s =>`\${s}`)` would.)

```
preg_replace('("|\')', '\\$0', $json)
```

Comment: It is being pulled from my db. I would like to be able to use the apostrophe in the text still though.

Comment: @Dan Yes, but you need to escape it in your JavaScript literal, i.e., `'Canada\\'s '`; just insert a reversed bar preceding your apostrophe. PHP has something for that, I guess.